# Wildfly Jakarta EE 10 Multipart forms missing

Tags: jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly

In the process of upgrading from Wildfly 25 to Wildfly 27 (and beyond), we are no longer seeing multipart forms.

The request parts is null (see below at the bottom). So, I'm not sure where it is getting eaten.

Here is the the web.conf

```
<web-app
xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_6_0.xsd"
version="6.0">
<display-name>ESG WebApplication</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/rest</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.pearson.esg.server.PRMSContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>SessionTimeoutCookieFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.oberon.esg.server.SessionTimeoutCookieFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SessionTimeoutCookieFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>ResponseHeaderFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.pearson.esg.server.ResponseHeaderFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ResponseHeaderFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <display-name>Initialize ESG Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>esg.InitServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.oberon.esg.server.InitServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <display-name>ESG Request Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>esg.RequestServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.oberon.esg.server.RequestServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <display-name>ESG Client Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>esg.ClientServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.oberon.esg.client.ClientServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>4</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>esg.InitServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/init</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>esg.RequestServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/request/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>esg.ClientServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/client</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<mime-mapping>
    <extension>pdf</extension>
    <mime-type>application/pdf</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>

<mime-mapping>
    <extension>css</extension>
    <mime-type>text/css</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>

<mime-mapping>
    <extension>jar</extension>
    <mime-type>application/x-java-archive</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>xml</extension>
    <mime-type>text/xml</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>


<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>esg.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>


<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

The POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.pearson.prms</groupId>
    <artifactId>PRMS</artifactId>
    <version>-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>esg</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.javadoc.failOnError>false</maven.javadoc.failOnError>
    </properties>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2</id>
            <name>Maven Central Repo</name>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>PearsonSnapshot</id>
            <name>PearsonSnapshot</name>
            <url>https://nexus2.pearsondev.com/nexus/content/repositories/PearsonSnapshot/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <finalName>esg</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java/com/oberon/esg/util</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>build.number</include>
                </includes>
                <targetPath>${basedir}/target/esg/WEB-INF/classes/com/oberon/esg/util</targetPath>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <targetPath>${basedir}/target/esg</targetPath>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>upload-war-to-server</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>upload</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <fromDir>${project.build.directory}</fromDir>
                    <includes>esg.war</includes>
                    <toDir>dev-tools/wildfly-11.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments</toDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- a copy of this connector needs to be in the static-content and needs to be updated in the Docker file -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j2-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Provided by Wildfly upgrade on each release ? -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.1.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.3.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- End of provided by Wildfly -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
            <version>0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload2-jakarta</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-M1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>  <!-- wildfly seems to have commons-lang3-3.12.0 -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.owasp.antisamy</groupId>
            <artifactId>antisamy</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.638</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Here is the multipart-form caught in Chrome:

```
------WebKitFormBoundary10g8buFFvhco7LAa
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="challenge"

a73152dadb6bd6d376f40590e4a...
------WebKitFormBoundary10g8buFFvhco7LAa
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="requestType"

downloadTooltip
------WebKitFormBoundary10g8buFFvhco7LAa--
```

Here is the post being caught with the traceback

```
parsePostRequestInputs:62, RequestInputs (com.oberon.esg.client)
doPost:95, ClientServlet (com.oberon.esg.client)
service:547, HttpServlet (jakarta.servlet.http)
service:614, HttpServlet (jakarta.servlet.http)
handleRequest:74, ServletHandler (io.undertow.servlet.handlers)
doFilter:129, FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl (io.undertow.servlet.handlers)
doFilter:72, ResponseHeaderFilter (com.pearson.esg.server)
doFilter:67, ManagedFilter (io.undertow.servlet.core)
doFilter:131, FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl (io.undertow.servlet.handlers)
doFilter:64, SessionTimeoutCookieFilter (com.oberon.esg.server)
doFilter:67, ManagedFilter (io.undertow.servlet.core)
doFilter:131, FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl (io.undertow.servlet.handlers)
handleRequest:84, FilterHandler (io.undertow.servlet.handlers)
handleRequest:62, ServletSecurityRoleHandler (io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security)
handleRequest:68, ServletChain$1 (io.undertow.servlet.handlers)
handleRequest:36, ServletDispatchingHandler (io.undertow.servlet.handlers)
lambda$handleRequest$1:68, ElytronRunAsHandler (org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server)
call:-1, 468564214 (org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler$$Lambda$1005)
apply:-1, 1566944025 (org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped$$Lambda$1006)
apply:-1, 1023282428 (org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped$$Lambda$1007)
runAsFunctionEx:103, FlexibleIdentityAssociation (org.wildfly.security.auth.server)
runAsFunctionEx:161, Scoped (org.wildfly.security.auth.server)
runAs:73, Scoped (org.wildfly.security.auth.server)
handleRequest:67, ElytronRunAsHandler (org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server)
handleRequest:68, RedirectDirHandler (io.undertow.servlet.handlers)
handleRequest:117, SSLInformationAssociationHandler (io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security)
handleRequest:57, ServletAuthenticationCallHandler (io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security)
handleRequest:43, PredicateHandler (io.undertow.server.handlers)
handleRequest:46, AbstractConfidentialityHandler (io.undertow.security.handlers)
handleRequest:64, ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler (io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security)
handleRequest:43, AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler (io.undertow.security.handlers)
handleRequest:38, CleanUpHandler (org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet)
handleRequest:43, PredicateHandler (io.undertow.server.handlers)
handleRequest:44, JACCContextIdHandler (org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc)
handleRequest:43, PredicateHandler (io.undertow.server.handlers)
handleRequest:54, RewriteCorrectingHandlerWrappers$PostWrapper$1 (org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment)
handleRequest:141, PredicatesHandler (io.undertow.predicate)
handleRequest:35, RewriteCorrectingHandlerWrappers$PreWrapper$1 (org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment)
handleRequest:51, GlobalRequestControllerHandler (org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment)
handleRequest:52, SendErrorPageHandler (io.undertow.servlet.handlers)
handleRequest:43, PredicateHandler (io.undertow.server.handlers)
handleFirstRequest:276, ServletInitialHandler (io.undertow.servlet.handlers)
call:135, ServletInitialHandler$2 (io.undertow.servlet.handlers)
call:132, ServletInitialHandler$2 (io.undertow.servlet.handlers)
call:48, ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1 (io.undertow.servlet.core)
call:43, ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1 (io.undertow.servlet.core)
lambda$create$0:1413, UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction (org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment)
call:-1, 1680829687 (org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$876)
lambda$create$0:1413, UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction (org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment)
call:-1, 1680829687 (org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$876)
lambda$create$0:1413, UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction (org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment)
call:-1, 1680829687 (org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$876)
lambda$create$0:1413, UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction (org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment)
call:-1, 1680829687 (org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$876)
dispatchRequest:256, ServletInitialHandler (io.undertow.servlet.handlers)
handleRequest:101, ServletInitialHandler$1 (io.undertow.servlet.handlers)
executeRootHandler:393, Connectors (io.undertow.server)
run:859, HttpServerExchange$1 (io.undertow.server)
run:35, ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable (org.jboss.threads)
safeRun:1990, EnhancedQueueExecutor (org.jboss.threads)
doRunTask:1486, EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody (org.jboss.threads)
run:1377, EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody (org.jboss.threads)
run:1282, XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1 (org.xnio)
run:829, Thread (java.lang)
```

Here is where I want to look at the multipart data.

```
    @MultipartForm
    public void parsePostRequestInputs(HttpServletRequest request, InputValidation validator) throws IOException
    {
        _filesToUpload = new HashMap<String, Part>();

        if (request.getContentType().contains("urlencoded"))
        {
            //
            // read the request
            //
            Map<String, String[]> params = request.getParameterMap();
            _entries = new String[params.keySet().size()];
            int pos = 0;
            for (String param : params.keySet()) {
               _entries[pos] = param + "=" + URLDecoder.decode(params.get(param)[0], StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
               pos++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _log.debug("Checking for multipart.");

            try {
                request.getParts();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                _entries = new String[0];
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                final Collection<Part> parts = request.getParts();
                List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (final Part part : parts)
                {
                    String fileItemFieldName = part.getSubmittedFileName();
                    if (!(fileItemFieldName.startsWith("fileUpload")))
                    {
                        temp.add(part.getName() + "=" + fileItemFieldName);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        String index = part.getName().substring(10);
                        _filesToUpload.put(index, part);

                        String fileItemName = part.getName();
                        if (fileItemName.length() > 30)
                        {
                            fileItemName = fileItemName.substring(0, 30);
                        }
                        temp.add("uploadPixName" + index + "=" + fileItemName);
                    }
                }
                _entries = temp.toArray(new String[temp.size()]);
            }
            catch (FileUploadException | ServletException e)
            {
                _log.error("There was an issue uploading files for the POST request. " + e);
            }
        }
    }
```

The request looks like this in the debugger:

```
request = {HttpServletRequestImpl@16372} "HttpServletRequestImpl [ POST /esg/client ]"
 exchange = {HttpServerExchange@16383} "HttpServerExchange{ POST /esg/client}"
 originalServletContext = {ServletContextImpl@16384} 
 servletContext = {ServletContextImpl@16384} 
 attributes = null
 servletInputStream = null
 reader = null
 cookies = null
 parts = null
 asyncStarted = false
 asyncContext = null
 queryParameters = null
 parsedFormData = null
 formParsingException = null
 characterEncoding = null
 readStarted = false
 sessionCookieSource = null
```

This happens for all of our multipart data requests. This is perhaps the simplest request. If we use get with URL encodings, everything works fine. Any ideas where the multipart data has gone?

TIA!

Comment: Is the `@MultipartForm` the RESTEasy annotation? if not where does that annotation come from?

Comment: @James I've tried it with and without the annotation. It originally (in the Wildfly 25/Java EE) it was not present.

Comment: What is the package name for that annotation? Either way, what I see looks okay. You could remove some things in the `web.xml`, but nothing that is breaking anything. I'm not as familiar with this from the servlet aspect, but maybe there is some info here https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/6.0/jakarta-servlet-spec-6.0#_MultipartConfig.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Thansks. I'll read that over again. I added explicit multipart-config most recently to the servlets. No luck there. In looking at my logs. I can see that the content type is showing (from a different run) multipart: type=multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarydQQWFRMlGGvUrWAv. So, the question is where are the parts? Let see if there is more that I can add to the config/

Comment: I doubt you have one, but do you have a reproducer?

Comment: @James Thanks for your thoughts. After further testing, my idea about multipart-config appears to be the solution. I've turned it on and off again. It clearly works only with it defined.

Comment: That `commons-fileupload2-jakarta` dependency is unnecessary and potentially dangerous. Get rid of it and rely on native Servlet API provided functionality. Moreover, you're already using it in form of `request.getPart()`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/2424824

Comment: @BalusC Thanks, I was able to refactor and use the getPart method consistently through the existing application.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that multipart servlets need to have multipart-config defined (or have an appropriate annotation). I'm not sure when this became required. However, it showed up in our migration from Wildfly 26 to Wildfly 27.

By modifying my web.xml to have multipart-config defined, things began working.

```
<servlet>
    <display-name>ESG Client Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>esg.ClientServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.oberon.esg.client.ClientServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>4</load-on-startup>
    <multipart-config>
        <location>/tmp</location>
        <max-file-size>20848820</max-file-size>
        <max-request-size>418018841</max-request-size>
        <file-size-threshold>1048576</file-size-threshold>
    </multipart-config>
</servlet>
```